# Using database column names as axis names for r plot

Tags: r, rmysql

I am extracting data from a database using RMySQL and then using this data to plot a graph.

The code I currently have is as follows:

```
con <- dbConnect(dbDriver('MySQL'), user = 'root', password = 'root', dbname='dbname')
df <- data.frame(dbGetQuery(con, paste('select * from test')))
plot(df$ID, df$UID, xlab='test1', ylab='test2', type='l')
```

This works absolutely fine but my question is how can I use the DB column name as the axis labels instead of hard coding the labels in?

Comment: The names of the data frame are the same as the names of the db? Then you could just call the names of the dataframe

Comment: That sounds simple! How would I do that? I'm new to R and still haven't got my head around the capabilities of it.

Comment: `data.frame` and `paste` in the `df<- ` statement are unnecessary since `dbGEtQuery` already returns a data frame and the argument to paste is already a character string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the names of the data frame that come from the data base use `names(df)` or if they are rownames use `rownames(df)`.

Then you can subset to one value, example, assuming that the names are in the column and the ID is the first column and the UID the second.

```
plot(df$ID, df$UID, xlab=names(df)[1], ylab=names(df)[2], type='l')
```